# Deleted chat messages still show links if they refer to another message

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat

If a user posts a message in chat that links directly to another chat message like

`12345689: You smell funny!`

The chat rightly highlights message `12345689` when you hover over `User: You smell funny!`

If the user or a moderator deletes the `You smell funny!` message, the text changes to `(removed)`, which again is expected.

**However**, hovering over `(removed)` still highlights the previously referred-to message, in this case `12345689`.  I have to assume this is unintentional behavior for a message that is ostensibly deleted.

[image]

Comment: Does this still happen for non-mods?

Comment: But how else will I know which deleted messages might be juicy enough to read?

Comment: @иɪvэЖєvɪɴ It looks like it does.  I'm not a mod in the SO-specific chat and I still get that behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I feel like this is pretty standard fare. What I mean is that most forum based websites will show [deleted] but if you rollover and/or click it will show the comment. I sort of agree with that as well; if you don't want to see the comment then don't click it. At the risk of sounding like a 1st-year philosophy student, personally I am scared of the day when the general mentality is to shift to permanent moderation.

Comment: I see what you mean now, but I'm still going to say that I think it should be like this but I think the message should be shown still. This way you can see to whom the comment was pointed and usually you can infer why. At least if the content was shown it would make more sense, but that is just my opinion.

Comment: (Pardon, I deleted my comment after I realized that I also misunderstood the bug report, differently. I've updated the screenshot.)

Comment: Well mods and the original poster can still see the message once it's deleted.  I don't think that removing the indication of what you are replying to for everyone else is somehow dangerous or covering up anything.