# Hovering over deleted messages shouldn't highlight what it replied to

Tags: feature-request, chat

[image: boo]

I hovered the mouse over the deleted message by tripleee, whose content used to be

```
:46713033 still up
```

Well now, message 46713033 is highlighted. But it shouldn't. The message that refers to it is deleted already.

I've confirmed that any user (including anonymous users - unlogged-in) can see the highlights, after page refresh.

Note that **this is not a duplicate of [Deleted chat messages still show links if they refer to another message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169675)**, as that one is a bug report that has been considered by design, **this is a feature request asking that the design be changed**.

Comment: Sudden downvotes, what??